# Stored procedures no mysql nao fazem validação de tipo?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Tenho uma stored procedure no meu mysql que é em simples, ela faz um select numa tabela e filtra por um id. Segue a store procedure:

```
create
definer procedure fn_get_client_data(IN _email varchar(100), IN _id_loja int)
BEGIN
      SELECT
        cliente_nome,
        telefone,
        created_at,
      FROM lead_cliente
    WHERE
        email = `_email`
    AND
        id_loja = `_id_loja`;
END;
```

Acontece que fiz uma implementação incorreta e passei os parâmetros invertidos.

```
CALL backoffice.fn_get_customer_list(4, 'email.cliente@gmail.com');
```

E mesmo assim a stored procedure foi executada trazendo zero resultados. Está correto trazer zero resultos, mas gostaria de saber:

**Ela nao faz validação de tipo? Foi passado um integer onde deveria ser um varchar e um varchar onde deveria ser um integer. Tentei encontrar isso na documentação mas nao achei algo falando sobre tipagem? No datagrip ele nao permite executar essa stored procedure, então imagino que a IDE faça essa validação, mas nao o banco em si.**

Answer (score 0):

Descobri o que era e como solucionar.

Nas configurações do mysql é possível definir o

```
sql_mode="STRICT_ALL_TABLES";
```

Ao executar esse comando, as stored procedures vão validar o tipo dos parâmetros.
Caso queira que a essa validação não ocorra, o seguinte comando pode ser executado:

```
 sql_mode="";
```

**Importante!**
Recomendo ler a documentação Mysql, pois o **sql_mode** aceita outros parâmetros além do *STRICT_ALL_TABLES*. Documentação:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html